# can I change uploaded app to appstore while it's in review?

Tags: ios, upload, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded a new version of my app to iTunes Connect and after the uploading process was over, I got the following warning:

> "the app references non-public selectors"

I think it is because of `FBGraphUser` of Facebook SDK.

If my app gets rejected, will it be possible for me to change the binary while it is still in review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can reject the binary while in review. Just go to iTunes connect and select edit binary and you'll find the button for rejecting the binary. Then you'll have to submit another binary and will loose your position in the line but that should not matter if the change is fundamental. If there is a warning then yes you should reject the binary. Repair your code and upload another one. Hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reject the binary and upload the new binary as well.
Cheers